# How do I reference the properties of a control from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub FormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim myClosed As Integer = 0
        Dim myProgress As Integer = 0
        Dim myReview As Integer = 0
        Dim myRejected As Integer = 0
        Dim myCompleted As Integer = 0
        Dim myImplemented As Integer = 0

        For Each item In MainWindow.DatabaseList.Items

            If item.Status = "Closed" Then
                myClosed += 1
            End If

            If item.Status = "In Progress" Then
                myProgress += 1
            End If

            If item.Status = "In Review" Then
                myReview += 1
            End If

            If item.Status = "Rejected" Then
                myRejected += 1
            End If

            If item.Status = "Completed" Then
                myCompleted += 1
            End If

            If item.Status = "Implemented" Then
                myImplemented += 1
            End If

        Next

        ClosedNr.Text = myClosed
        ProgressNr.Text = myProgress
        ReviewNr.Text = myReview
        RejectedNr.Text = myRejected
        CompletedNr.Text = myCompleted
        ImplementedNr.Text = myImplemented


    End Sub
End Class
```

I get this error when I try to reference the MainWindow class.

```
Error   BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

I tried setting the MainWindow FieldModifier to public but it doesn't fix the error.

I also tried:

```
Dim myMainWindow as MainWindow = New MainWindow
```

But when doing this, my DatabaseList.Items.Count returns 0.

Project is VB.Net, but tagged C# because I can code in C# as well.

Comment: @zaggler What are they then? Controls? I am trying to get the Items of a ListView from another class. Project is VB.Net, but tagged C# because I can code in C# as well.

Comment: You can try `Application.OpenForms[formName]` to get the `MainWindow` instance or pass an instance of your `MainWindow` to the constructor of `Form1`

Comment: @SteveKrozer I read that wrong, apologies. How are you trying to access mainwindow, from where? Anyways, look into what Charles mentioned above.

Comment: @zaggler The WPF Application Window has a button that opens the form, when the form opens I try to get the ListView Items from a "DatabaseList" ListView, but when trying to reference the MainWindow class (with the ListView and its items in a For Each), I get the error you can see in the description. So this line gives the error: For Each item In MainWindow.DatabaseList.Items.

Comment: `The WPF Application Window` so this is `WPF`, not `WinForms`? Or are you using `WinForms` inside `WPF`?

Comment: @zaggler it is both, the WPF Application Window OPENS a WinForm Window. But the project was made in WPF Application.

Comment: OK, you'll need to pass an instance of `Window` to `Form1` constructor as mentioned already Charles. Something like `Public Sub New(ByVal mainWindow As MainWindow)` inside of `Form1` etc... OR the best approach is to pass a collection of some sort of your items. What type of item is stored in `MainWindow.DatabaseList.Items`?

Comment: @zaggler unfortunately I have no clue (I don't understand) how to do that :(, isn't it what I did in the description (Dim myMainWindow as MainWindow = New MainWindow) ?

Comment: @zaggler I have created a "myRow" class with multiple properties and passed it to the ListView with this: DatabaseList.Items.Add(New myRow With{.ID = myVar}).

Comment: OK, pass the `MainWindow.DatabaseList.Items` to the constructor of `Form1`. So add this constructor to `Form1`: `Public Sub New(ByVal items As System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection)`. Then when you construct a new instance of `Form1` pass your collection into it. You can assign the `items` to a read only property and then access them anytime you need. You'll also have to cast each item out as a `myRow` object to get access to those properties. So something like `For Each row As myRow In yourcollection)`....

Comment: @zaggler this worked, thank you, I learned something new, I'd like to not get banned on SO but it seems I can't avoid it (again), newbies don't always know what they're looking for so I have to ask questions that aren't very clear because even I don't know what I'm doing. 

Still, thank you, and Charles too. This account probably has two questions left so I'll ask whenever I find something else I can't solve by myself.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ItemCollection from a WPF Window Class delivered to your WF Window Class you have to do the following:

1. Declare a new event in your WF Window Class like this:

   Public Sub New(ByVal items As ItemCollection)

   End Sub
2. Go to the event in your WPF Window class that manages the WF Window Class and add the argument like this:

   Private Sub Dashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

   ```
            Dim myWindow As Form1 = New Form1(DatabaseList.Items)

            myWindow.Show()

        End Sub
   ```

Then you can access the ItemCollection with a simple:

```
For Each item As myRow In items
    Next
```

Thanks to Charles and zaggler for finding the solution.